# What type of underlayment should be used when installing engineered floors?

Tags: flooring, floor, underlayment

I'm going to install floating engineered wood floor in a 3rd floor condo. It has plywood subfloor. My biggest concern is the noise of walking on the floor that people below me will suffer.

My question is, does a good/premium underlayment help reduce or deaden the sound? How about foam vs cork underlayment?

Comment: You can get the standard underlayment from one of the box stores but I would recommend you going to a flooring speciality store, most do have higher quality underlayment options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several good foam type underlayments available. For maximum sound proofing, I'd probably recommend one of the high density closed cell foam pads as opposed to the standard blue or white 1/8" lightweight styles.  You may have to visit a flooring specialty store, I have never seen the better grades in stock at the box stores, although they may be able to order it for you.  The product description on the better grades will specifically mention superior sound deadening. Good luck.

Comment: I checked out a lumberliquidators local store and they do have effective sound reducing underlayment for sale at $60 per 100 sqft.